# Is there a GCC version of the NASM ORG instruction?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm

I'm currently making an OS, and when I tried to add C support, I ran into a bit of a problem... In assembly, each program on my OS starts with `ORG 32768` (the NASM compiler preprocessor instruction for offsetting the origin of the code), but I can't seem to find anything on a way to do this using the GCC compiler for C. So, my question is, how would one achieve this (offsetting the code's origin) in C using GCC? (and yes, I have looked it up before asking, even checked [GNU's official GCC's C preprocessor documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/))

Comment: You can set where the code will go by using linker scripts, but I don't know any ways to archive it in C.

Comment: You can't do this from C. If you're using the binary format with NASM then you'll to get the same effect you'll need to use linker scripts like MikeCAT said. You'll also need to write your own C startup code and then you'll need to port the C library if you want to use that.

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks, I haven't handmade my own linker scripts before (didn't need to, I wrote the kernel in assembly), but I'm sure I can figure that out with the wonderful Google.

Comment: @RossRidge I've already ported enough of the C library to make a basic hello world program in C, but I appreciate the advice, and by C startup code, what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: The code that initializes the C library and then calls `main`. It's where a C program first begins executing.

Comment: @RossRidge Ohhhh you meant that (facepalm) sorry, OS development = little sleep haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORG and .ORG go back to the days when you wrote programs in assembly and didnt necessarily need a linker.

The gnu tools dont support it AFAIK.

start.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $0xA000,%rsp
    callq fun
    jmp .
```

fun.c

```
unsigned int fun ( void )
{
    return(7);
}
```

fun.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .data : { *(.data*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

build commands

```
as start.s -o start.o
gcc -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -c fun.c -o fun.o
ld -T fun.ld start.o fun.o -o fun
```

which produces this program:

```
0000000000008000 <_start>:
    8000:   48 c7 c4 00 a0 00 00    mov    $0xa000,%rsp
    8007:   e8 04 00 00 00          callq  8010 <fun>
    800c:   eb fe                   jmp    800c <_start+0xc>
    800e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax

0000000000008010 <fun>:
    8010:   b8 07 00 00 00          mov    $0x7,%eax
    8015:   c3                      retq
```

I used an entry point of 0x8000 (32768).

If by gcc you meant the gnu tools and just wanted to do assembly language then that makes it a bit simpler, you only need the binutils package not gcc.  But you still need the linker and use the ORIGIN in the very simpler linker script example above where you would have used .ORG inline with the assembly.

start.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $0xA000,%rsp
    mov $0x7,%eax
    add $0x1,%eax
    jmp .
```

same linker script as above

```
as start.s -o start.o
ld -T fun.ld start.o -o fun
```

producing

```
0000000000008000 <_start>:
    8000:   48 c7 c4 00 a0 00 00    mov    $0xa000,%rsp
    8007:   b8 07 00 00 00          mov    $0x7,%eax
    800c:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
    800f:   eb fe                   jmp    800f <_start+0xf>
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped tremendously :)